# Adding jar file to jpype makes java crash

Tags: java, python, flask, jpype, jaydebeapi

I'm using flask-appbuilder to build an application. To submit a form to execute ddl, I add a jar file to jpype when startJVM(), but java always crashes. Below is my code:

```
import jaydebeapi
from flask import flash

def execute_ddl(dic):
    def set_up_conn(dic):
        conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=dic['jclass'],
                              url=dic['url'],
                              driver_args=[dic['driver_name'], 
                              dic['driver_params']],
                              jars=dic['jars'])
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(dic['ddl'])
        output = curs.fetchall()
        print(output)
        curs.close()
        conn.close()
    try:
        import jpype
        if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
            jvmPath = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
            flash(str(jvmPath), 'info')
            jpype.startJVM(jvmPath, "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=/lib/uber-hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar")

        if not jpype.isThreadAttachedToJVM():
            jpype.attachThreadToJVM()
            jpype.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().\
         setContextClassLoader(jpype.java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
        set_up_conn(dic)
        # post process form
        flash('{} is submitted!'.format(dic['ddl']), 'info')
    except Exception as e:
        flash(str(e), 'info')
```

This is the crashing error and I tried "ulimit -c unlimited" but no luck.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fce15f978b9, pid=12, tid=0x00007fce0f7fe700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [_jpype.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so+0x3f8b9]  
JPJavaEnv::NewLocalRef(_jobject*)+0x9
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid12.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `multi_threading` which is the reason.

Jaydebeapi uses jpype to start JVM. You need to use `jpype.attachThreadToJVM()` in the thread body to make the JVM usable from that thread. You can use `jpype.isThreadAttachedToJVM()` to check it is attached.

Comment: you can refer to jpype document ,the threading part.https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#overview